# Exception while property mapping at property path "": Property was not found in target object of type "In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User"

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I try to extend the Extension femanager with a new Field, customernumber. I set up the TCA Definition and the Model for this Field. In Typoscript I set my Model and map it to `fe_users`.

```
config.tx_extbase{
    persistence{
        classes{
            In2\Femanager\Domain\Model\User {
                subclasses {
                    0 = FederhenSchneider\Extendfemanager\Domain\Model\User
                }
            }
            FederhenSchneider\Extendfemanager\Domain\Model\User {
                mapping {
                    tableName = fe_users
                    recordType = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
    objects {
        In2\Femanager\Controller\NewController.className = FederhenSchneider\Extendfemanager\Controller\NewController
        In2\Femanager\Controller\EditController.className = FederhenSchneider\Extendfemanager\Controller\EditController

        In2\Femanager\Domain\Validator\ServersideValidator.className = FederhenSchneider\Extendfemanager\Domain\Validator\CustomServersideValidator
        In2\Femanager\Domain\Validator\ClientsideValidator.className = FederhenSchneider\Extendfemanager\Domain\Validator\CustomClientsideValidator
    }
}

plugin.tx_femanager {
    view {
        partialRootPaths {
            10 = EXT:extendfemanager/Resources/Private/Partials/
        }
    }
}
```

In the Backend the Field is ok. When I send my Formular in the Frontend I get this Error:

> Exception while property mapping at property path "": Property
>   "customernumber" was not found in target object of type
>   "In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User".

I don`t understand why he is looking in the Model from In2Code and not in my Model.

My System:
PHP 7.0
TYPO3 7.6.18
Femanager 2.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Femanager 2.6.0 uses `In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User` (In2code instead of In2) as namespace.

Corrected Typoscript:

```
config.tx_extbase{
    persistence{
        classes{
            In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User {
                subclasses {
                    0 = FederhenSchneider\Extendfemanager\Domain\Model\User
                }
            }
            FederhenSchneider\Extendfemanager\Domain\Model\User {
                mapping {
                    tableName = fe_users
                    recordType = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
    objects {
        In2code\Femanager\Controller\NewController.className = FederhenSchneider\Extendfemanager\Controller\NewController
        In2code\Femanager\Controller\EditController.className = FederhenSchneider\Extendfemanager\Controller\EditController

        In2code\Femanager\Domain\Validator\ServersideValidator.className = FederhenSchneider\Extendfemanager\Domain\Validator\CustomServersideValidator
        In2code\Femanager\Domain\Validator\ClientsideValidator.className = FederhenSchneider\Extendfemanager\Domain\Validator\CustomClientsideValidator
    }
}

plugin.tx_femanager {
    view {
        partialRootPaths {
            10 = EXT:extendfemanager/Resources/Private/Partials/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thx Christoph you are right. I looked only at my Namespace and did not see that the In2code Namespace is not correct ;-).